# How does ANF increase GFR?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, kidney, human-physiology

ANF as we know reduce the Na+ uptake and K+ removal in the distal tubules and it also functions as a Vasodialator (?) But again it says that ANF increases the Glomerular filtrate ? But if it is acting has a Vasoldialator (*ie, antagonistic to Vasopressin*) how is it increasing the GFR ? Shouldnt it lower the GFR ?

---

ANF - Atrial Natriuretic Factor also called Atrial Natriuretic Peptide

GFR - Glomerular Filtration Rate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ANF (Atrial Natriuretic Factor more commonly known as ANP - atrial natriuretic peptide) squeezes (vasoconstricts) the efferent arteriole. This means the pressure in the glomerulus is higher (like if you squeeze the end of a hose) and so more fluid is squeezed out i.e. the glomerular filtration rate (GFR) is higher. It also dilates the afferent which means more fluid is going in, further increasing GFR [(*Marin-Grez et al.*)](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v324/n6096/abs/324473a0.html)

[image: Glomerulus]

Comment: Why is this answer down voted?

Comment: Someone has been downvoting all my answers for whatever reason. Assume they're trying to get me under 4000.

Comment: I found two downvotes and I upvoted once to get the -1 status. Good answer though. I think it will be reversed soon! Good luck

Comment: It seems the community is very reluctant to upvote good answers. Most of my rep comes from answers to silly questions vs well researched answer to good questions

Comment: I downvoted because of the lack of references, the unclear picture, the use of acronyms and the ample use of technical terms. Should have let you know earlier. I also downvoted the question for similar reasons, but after@CRags made the edits I removed the downvote and close-vote as well. I am not downvoting person-based btw - everyone is free to like or dislike particular questions and answers isn't it?

Comment: And don't assume the worst when folks downvote. Downvoting helps to  improve questions and answers. My downvotes have ***nothing*** to do with personal missions to bring someones rep <4k, nor has it ***anything*** to do with a reluctance to upvote! Personal vendettas can be reported to moderators btw.

Comment: @ChrisStronks: Thank you for your feedback. Comments and feedback help improve answers whereas simply down voting leave the author of an answer confused. In the future make sure to leave comments when you down vote to avoid not being helpful. I have improved the answer by explaining acronyms and adding a reference. There isn't a better picture than this which has ANP on it.

Comment: @AndroidPenguin - you are totally right. Normally I leave a comment. My bad. +1 :-)

Comment: So the summary is that ANP vasodilates the afferent arterioles and constricts the efferect arteriole ?